# how to properly use jq to sort json output

Tags: json, sorting, jq

Need some assistance configuring this `jq` command against `json` type output.

Example `testout.out`:

```
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5aaaa017e4b09780301b6c18"), "account" : "abc", "profile" : "catch", "settings" : { "region" : "us-east-1" } }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5ad894fbe4b0657c569ed5d8"), "account" : "def", "profile" : "test", "settings" : { "region" : "eu-central-1" } }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5ae127dee4b06990170a0eb4"), "account" : "ght", "profile" : "main", "settings" : { "region" : "us-east-1" } }
```

I'm trying to sort by `region`.

Trying this command:

```
cat testout.out | jq -s -c 'sort_by(.region) |.[]'
```

Getting this output:
`parse error: Invalid numeric literal at line 1, column 20`

Expecting alphabetical sort on `region`:

```
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5ad894fbe4b0657c569ed5d8"), "account" : "def", "profile" : "test", "settings" : { "region" : "eu-central-1" } }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5aaaa017e4b09780301b6c18"), "account" : "abc", "profile" : "catch", "settings" : { "region" : "us-east-1" } }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5ae127dee4b06990170a0eb4"), "account" : "ght", "profile" : "main", "settings" : { "region" : "us-east-1" } }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`jq` tries to parse values like `ObjectId("5aaaa017e4b09780301b6c18")` as numeric value and gives you an expected error in terms of JSON validation.

If your `testout.out` file would be as follows:

```
{ "_id" : "ObjectId(\"5aaaa017e4b09780301b6c18\")", "account" : "abc", "profile" : "catch", "settings" : { "region" : "us-east-1" } }
{ "_id" : "ObjectId(\"5ad894fbe4b0657c569ed5d8\")", "account" : "def", "profile" : "test", "settings" : { "region" : "eu-central-1" } }
{ "_id" : "ObjectId(\"5ae127dee4b06990170a0eb4\")", "account" : "ght", "profile" : "main", "settings" : { "region" : "us-east-1" } }
```

you'll be able to perform the needed sorting:

```
jq -sc 'sort_by(.settings.region)[]' testout.out
```

The output:

```
{"_id":"ObjectId(\"5ad894fbe4b0657c569ed5d8\")","account":"def","profile":"test","settings":{"region":"eu-central-1"}}
{"_id":"ObjectId(\"5aaaa017e4b09780301b6c18\")","account":"abc","profile":"catch","settings":{"region":"us-east-1"}}
{"_id":"ObjectId(\"5ae127dee4b06990170a0eb4\")","account":"ght","profile":"main","settings":{"region":"us-east-1"}}
```

Comment: @noober, to parse JSON you should adjust your input file to make it valid

Answer (score 0):

You could probably get away with this pre-filter to convert the JSON-like objects to valid JSON:

```
 sed 's/: ObjectId("\([^"]*\)")/: "ObjectId(\1)"/g'
```